# Center a container row on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I read online that you can use the below code to center a row in a container using bootstrap, but I haven't been able to get it to work and I think it might have something to do with the css.

`<div class="row justify-content-center">`

Below is the current code. There was no `.portfolio` in the template and it won't let me add it.

```css
.portfolio #portfolio-flters {
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  list-style: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.portfolio #portfolio-flters li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #444444;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.portfolio #portfolio-flters li:hover,
.portfolio #portfolio-flters li.filter-active {
  color: #593d4a;
}

.portfolio #portfolio-flters li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-info {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  padding: 15px;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-info h4 {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #191919;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-info p {
  color: #4c4c4c;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-info .preview-link,
.portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-info .details-link {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  font-size: 24px;
  top: calc(50% - 18px);
  color: #333333;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-info .preview-link:hover,
.portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-info .details-link:hover {
  color: #593d4a;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-info .details-link {
  right: 10px;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-links {
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-links a {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 2px;
  font-size: 28px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-links a:hover {
  color: #593d4a;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item:hover .portfolio-info {
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section id="dataviz/wordclouds" class="portfolio">
  <p></p>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Word Clouds</h3>

    <div class="portfolio-container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="150">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-4 portfolio-item filter-wc">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="portfolio-info">
            <h4>20 Nov</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 portfolio-item filter-wc">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="portfolio-info">
            <h4>21 Nov</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 portfolio-item" filter-wc>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="portfolio-info">
            <h4>22 Nov</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 portfolio-item filter-wc">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="portfolio-info">
            <h4>23 Nov</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 portfolio-item filter-wc">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="portfolio-info">
            <h4>24 Nov</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And this is an image of the problem, the last row isn't centered:

[image: example of the problem where the last row is not centered]

Thank you so much in advance for the help!

Comment: Check out [This Codepen](https://www.codeply.com/go/amixFv1StE/bootstrap-4-center-last-column-in-row) See if that helps ..

Comment: @Zak Thanks! I tried that but it still didn't work. I added 'mx-auto' to each div class but it still wasn't centered :(

Comment: CSS is fine, it's just that you have missed to close the `</div>` tag before closing section tag.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: The image doesn't match the output of the demo above. The demo seems to do what you're asking for already. FYI, don't use paragraphs for spacing. Use margin or padding, both of which Bootstrap provides via classes. Also, you're missing a closing div tag somewhere. See the formatted code above.

Comment: Sometimes this filter thing is in a `class-` sometimes not `<div class="col-lg-4 portfolio-item" filter-wc>`.  Please clean up the syntax before you post.